# starting batch with another batch cause multiple running

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file

I have batch and start another batch with first one and I noticed that second batch is ran many times in 1 second appart. Some other with 1 minute appart even if I use `TIMEOUT /T 1000`

I see this is not a problem only with one batch set which start another batch, but it happend with all batches which are ran by another batch.
Can someone help me with this, how to solve this problem
I tried with

```
start /B batch.bat
call batch.bat
start cmd /c "batch.bat"
```

If I use this script it makes batch to start 6 times in 1 second appart, but it should only 1 time.

```
set startdir=%cd%
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd %%i
    if exist "new_copy_sendmail.bat" call "new_copy_sendmail.bat"
    cd %startdir%
)
```

Comment: Without your exact batch files I can't replicate the behaviour. Your 2nd example will iterate subfolders and call each `"new_copy_sendmail.bat"` it finds there. BTW stepping in/out subfolders might be easier using pushd/popd.

Comment: Try `"start /wait new_copy_sendmail.bat"` instead of `"new_copy_sendmail.bat"`

Comment: that's not working it is the same

Comment: Perhaps in the `for /d` loop you need to add a line such as `if exist "new_copy_sendmail.bat" echo "%%~fi\new_copy_sendmail.bat"` and see if there's 6 different batch files within that directory structure. To me it sounds like it is executing each batch found and it finds the batch 6 different times.

Answer (score 0):

It's running once for each folder that contains a batch file with that name *and* once for each folder with a space or special character in it if the batch file also exists in `startdir` since the `cd` will fail if the folder has a space or special character (like ampersand). you can fix it by changing the `cd` call to `cd "%%~i"` instead. This syntax will allow you to `cd` to directories with spaces or other special characters.

A cleaner method would be to run it only for the specific files instead of jumping into the subdirectories with `forfiles`. This will only run once per `new_copy_sendmail.bat` file in the current directory or any subdirectory.

```
forfiles /m "new_copy_sendmail.bat" /S /C "cmd /c call @relpath"
```